# Using a hash as a reference is deprecated

Tags: perl

I have a problem with a Perl script but don't know why. I have something like this

```
..
$ref = pfget($Pf, "criteria");
%criteria= %$ref;
..
..
foreach $key (keys %criteria) {
  $expr = %criteria->{$key};
  ..
}
```

The line `$expr = %criteria->{$key}` gives me an error

```
Using a hash as a reference is deprecated
```

I've tried `$expr = $criteria{$key}` but the script is not working as it should be.

Have you got any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: shouldn't it be `$criteria->{$key}` ?

Comment: `$expr=$criteria{$key}` is the right way. What do you mean by `the script is not working as it should be`?

Comment: ALWAYS `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Deprecated? Depreciated?

Comment: It's [Deprecate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)

Comment: If `pfget()` returns a `%hash` you can just use a code reference to access it instead of copying the values around.  This should avoid the warning.

Answer (score 10):

`%criteria` in scalar context is suppose to return statistics about the hash.

```
$ perl -E'my %h = ( a=>1, b=>2, c=>3 ); say scalar %h'
3/8
```

So

```
%criteria->{$key}
```

means

```
"3/8"->{$key}
```

But a bug in Perl causes it to behave as

```
(\%criteria)->{$key}
```

The warning is telling you that your code is buggy because your code is relying on a bug in Perl. Use

```
$criteria{$key}
```

or avoid the wastefulness of creating `%criteria` and use

```
for my $key (keys %$ref) {
   ... $ref->{$key} ...
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more specific. I was hoping to know more about the historical background and why if it is a bug it hasn't been fixed yet (ramifications on legacy code, etc.)

Comment: @Zaid, Don't know how it came to be, but it's not fixed yet because 1) a deprecation cycle is in order because people have been doing `%criteria->{$key}` meaning `$criteria{$key}`, and 2) there's no rush since because noone wants to do `"3/8"->{$key}`. In other words, the bug is merely that it allows inconsistent code style at no benefit (along the same lines as `@a[$x]`), something a warning can handle.

Comment: Great explanation ++ I'm trying to organize my mental storage for the syntax now available with 5.20 "hash slices". Whenever I copy a hash instead of taking a reference it feels clunky (*i.e.* anything ressembling `%z = %y`). The flexibility of the [new hash slice syntax](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/07/perl-5-20-introduces-keyvalue-slices/) seems like a more selective way to copy data around.

Comment: @G. Cito, Note that `%foo->{...}` doesn't conflict with hash slices. That's [`$hr->%{'a','b','c'}`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408).

Comment: @ikegami, wow amazing answer. Can you explain "3/8"?  What statistic does it refer to?

Answer (score 3):

`%criteria` refers to the whole hash.

```
%criteria= %$ref;
```

Copies the entire hash referred to by `$ref` into a new hash called `%criteria`.

To access a value inside that hash you would just use `$criteria{$key}`.

If you want to use the reference (more efficient!) you could just use `$ref->{$key}`.